# Using de Moivre's Theorem, show that: $\cos(5\theta)=\cos^5\theta-10 \cos^3\theta \sin^2\theta+5 \cos\theta \sin^4\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, binomial-coefficients

I started stating that: $$(\cos\theta+i \sin\theta)^5=\sum_{k=0}^5 \binom{5}{k} (\cos\theta)^{5-k}\cdot (i \sin\theta)^k$$
Then, I apply the binomial theorem and develop, so I ended up with this, but arranged:

$$=\cos^5(\theta)-10 \cos^3(\theta) \sin^2(\theta)+5 \cos(\theta) \sin^4(\theta)+5\cos^4(\theta)-i \sin(\theta)\\-10 \cos^2(\theta) i \sin^3(\theta)+i \sin^5(\theta)$$

So you can see I get what I wanted to obtain, but I can't or dont know how to get rid of this part: $$5 \cos^4(\theta)-i \sin(\theta)-10 \cos^2(\theta) i \sin^3(\theta)+i \sin^5(\theta)$$
Until now, I got: $$i \sin(\theta)[\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)]$$
I really don't know how to proceed, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is $sen$ different from $sin?$ And better formatting is `\sin` and `\cos`.

Comment: Sorry, I edit right now

Comment: @ThomasAndrews In Spanish, sine is "seno."

Comment: Also, you forgot the the binomials $\binom5k$ in the expansion of $(a+b)^5.$

Comment: You should have $5i\cos^{4}(θ)\sin(θ)$ rather than $5\cos^{4}(θ)-i\sin(θ)$. If you correct that, then just group all the terms with the $i$ factor and compare real and imaginary part with the left side

Comment: @SeanRoberson I was vaguely aware of that, but this question used both terms, so I wanted some clarity.

Answer (score 3):

$$(\cos\theta+i \sin\theta)^5=\sum_{k=0}^5 \binom{5}{k} (\cos\theta)^{5-k}\cdot (i \sin\theta)^k$$

The idea is to let the "real part of LHS" equals the "real part of RHS". (surely, "imaginary part of LHS" equals the "imaginary part of RHS"). But for this problem, we only need to show the "real part = real part".

For LHS, the real part is:

$$\Re(\cos\theta+i \sin\theta)^5=\Re e^{i5\theta}=\Re(\cos(5\theta)+i\sin(5\theta))=\cos(5\theta)$$

For RHS, the real part doesn't contain the factor $i$, and this happens only for those terms when $k$ takes even integers, namely, $k=0, 2, 4$.

For RHS, the real part is:

$$\Re \sum_{k=0}^5 \binom{5}{k} (\cos\theta)^{5-k}\cdot (i \sin\theta)^k=\cos^5(\theta)-10 \cos^3(\theta) \sin^2(\theta)+5 \cos(\theta) \sin^4(\theta)$$

Therefore, we get:

$$\cos(5\theta)=\cos^5(\theta)-10 \cos^3(\theta) \sin^2(\theta)+5 \cos(\theta) \sin^4(\theta)$$

The proof is completed.

Answer (score 0):

On the left hand side, use de Moivre's theorem. On the right hand side, make sure you expand carefully.

Then use the fact that two complex numbers are equal if and only if their real and imaginary parts are equal.

Comment: But why? I applyed the binomial theorem to the part of $$i\sin(5\theta)$$

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a mistake in your expansion; your term which reads $5\cos^4\theta - i\sin\theta$, should in fact be $5i\cos^4\theta\sin\theta$.

By De Moivre’s theorem, $(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)^5=\cos 5\theta + i\sin 5\theta$. You should then equate real and imaginary parts; since the real part of the expansion is $\cos 5\theta$, you can ignore all the imaginary terms you have in the expansion.